# Loading first few observations of data set without reading entire data set (Stata 13.1)?

Tags: stata

(Stata/MP 13.1)

I am working with a set of massive data sets that takes an extremely long time to load. I am currently looping through all the data sets to load them each time.

Is it possible to just tell Stata to load in the first 5 observations of each dataset (or in general the first `n` data sets in each use command) without actually having to load the entire data set? Otherwise, if I were to load in the entire data set and then just keep the first 5 observations, the process takes extremely long time.

Here are two work-arounds I have already tried

1. `use in 1/5 using mydata` : I think this is more efficient than just loading the data and then keeping the observations you want in a different line, but I think it still reads in the entire data set.
2. First load all the data sets, then save copies of all the data sets to just be the first 5 observations, and then just use the copies: This is cumbersome as I have a lot of different files; I would very much prefer just a direct way to read in the first 5 observations without having to resort to this method and without having to read the entire data set.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say using `in` is the natural way to do this in Stata, but testing shows 
you are correct: it really makes no "big" difference, given the size of the data set. An example is (with 148,000,000 observations)

```
sysuse auto, clear
expand 2000000

tempfile bigfile
save "`bigfile'", replace

clear
timer on 1
use "`bigfile'"
timer off 1

clear
timer on 2
use "`bigfile'" in 1/5
timer off 2

timer list
timer clear
```

Resulting in

```
. timer list
   1:      6.44 /        1 =       6.4400
   2:      4.85 /        1 =       4.8480
```

I find that surprising since `in` seems really efficicient in other contexts.
I would contact Stata Tech support (and/or search around, including www.statalist.com) only to ask why `in` isn't much faster
(independently of you finding some other strategy to handle this problem).

It's worth using, of course; but not fast enough for many applications.

In terms of workflow, your second option might be the best. Leave the computer running while the smaller datasets are created (use a *for* loop), and get back to your regular coding/debugging once that's finished. This really depends on what you're doing, so it may work or not.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found the solution. If you run

```
use mybigdata if runiform() <= 0.0001
```

Stata will take a random sample of 0.0001 of the data set without reading the entire data set.

Thanks!

Vincent

**Edit: 4/28/2015 (1:58 PM EST)**
My apologies. It turns out the above was actually **not** a solution to the original question. It seems that on my system there was high variability in the speed of using

```
use mybigdata if runiform() <= 0.0001
```

each time I ran it. When I posted that the above was a solution, I think when I ran the code, it just happened to be a faster instance. However, as I now am repeatedly running

```
use mybigdata if runiform() <= 0.0001
```

vs.

```
use in 1/5 using mydata
```

I am actually finding that

```
use in 1/5 using mydata
```

is on average faster.

In general, my question is simply how to read in a portion of a Stata data set without having to read in the entire data set for computational purposes especially when the data set is really large.

**Edit: 4/28/2015 (2:50 PM EST)**
In total, I have 20 datasets, each with between 5 - 15 million observations. I only need to keep 8 of the variables (There are 58-65 variables in each data set). Below is the output from the first four "describe, short" statements.

```
2004 action1

Contains data from 2004action1.dta
  obs:    15,039,576                          
 vars:            64                          30 Oct 2014 17:09
size: 2,827,440,288                          
Sorted by: 

2004 action2578

Contains data from 2004action2578.dta
  obs:    13,449,087                          
 vars:            59                          30 Oct 2014 17:16
size: 2,098,057,572                          
Sorted by:  

2005 action1

Contains data from 2005action1.dta
  obs:    15,638,296                          
 vars:            65                          30 Oct 2014 16:47
size: 3,143,297,496                          
Sorted by:  

2005 action2578

Contains data from 2005action2578.dta
  obs:    14,951,428                          
 vars:            59                          30 Oct 2014 17:03
size: 2,362,325,624                          
Sorted by:
```

Thanks!

Vincent

Comment: It's a good thing you've found a solution, but frankly, I don't understand why that works. I believe your line of code computes a random number for each observation, then compares it with `0.0001`, and incorporates the observation accordingly. So this involves checking each observation, i.e. the whole data set. In fact, tests on my machine show this takes double the time an `in`does. The second point is that your original question nowhere mentions you want a random sample; you may want to edit it. Third point is you get a variable number of observations. Fourth point, use `set seed` to reprod.

Comment: Hi Roberto. Thanks for your help. In fact, I have just edited my answer in response to your post, and I realize that I did not in fact find a solution. Please see my edit for details; however, I definitely appreciate your tips and advice!

Comment: No problem. Just curious: how many observations and variables does your original data set have? You should present the output of `describe, short` in your original post. Do you need to keep all variables? How many files are you working with?

Comment: Sure, I have put answers to your questions in my latest edit above.